# sql asp.net send email c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

if you could please help me out... i am try to create o forgot password method.access my database and send an e-mail. if you please help me out since i don't have a lot of experience. thanking you in advance. Login is unique. C#

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
        cmd.CommandText = "select Password from Person where Login= @Login ";
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        string Password = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = sqlCon;
        cmd1.CommandText = "select e_mail from Person where Login= @Login "; 
        cmd1.Connection.Open();
        string e_mail = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

        if (Login.Text.Equals("@Login"))
        {

           Class1 S = new Class1();
           S.sendMail(e_mail, "Your Password request", Password);
           Response.Write("<script>");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can make one call to sql instead of two,
try somthing like this  (not tested!)

```
var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select e_mail, Password from Person where Login= @Login ", sqlCon);            
cmd.Connection.Open();            

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login", Email.Text));

string email = "", password = "";

using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        email = sdr.GetString(0);
        password = sdr.GetString(1);
    }
}
cmd.Connection.Close();
cmd.Dispose();



SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("your smtp");
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("YOU");
mailMessage.To.Add(email);

mailMessage.Subject = "password recovery";
mailMessage.Body = "hello " + email + " your password : " + password;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: again is outputting an error  that {Must declare the scalar variable "@Login" }

Answer (score 0):

To send mail use [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx). Configure the client in [WebConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx). To create the e-mail message use [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx). Should be pretty self explanatory.

I have no idea how your user database is designed but having two queries to get the data seems excessive. Construct a query that returns both the e-mail and password.

Also it is bad practice to have user passwords unencrypted. Consider providing an alternative solution (such as resetting passwords instead of returning passwords).

Comment: i have the encrypted i am trying to access them from the database  and that is the problem